# Redirecting URL Not Working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wanted to add authorization before accessing all web pages. So I have used the following configuration in web.config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms loginUrl="~/Login/Login.aspx" />
</authentication>
<authorization>
   <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

After this for every page Login.aspx asked, But after logged in successfully Redirection is not working with below code.

```
//http://localhost:55217/Login/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fHome%2fdeleteUser.aspx

if (returnMsg == "Success") {
    string query0 = Request.QueryString[0];
    finalStr = "~" + query0;
    Response.Redirect(finalStr, false);

    //Session["Login"] = username;
    //Response.Redirect("~/Home/Home.aspx");
    //Response.Redirect("/Home/HomeTest.aspx");
} else {
    StatusLabel.Attributes["style"] = "color:red; font-weight:bold;";
    StatusLabel.Text = "Error: Username or Password Wrong";
}
```

It is staying on the Login page again asking for credentials. But not showing error `"Error: Username or Password Wrong"`

Any ideas why it is not working?

Comment: What does 'Redirection is not working' mean? Does it stay on the login page? Do you get an error message? Something else?

Comment: its staying on Login page only @user469104

Comment: It's staying on login page? Or it attempts to load the other page but can't because it's not authorized? Watch the network traffic with your browser's developer tools.

Comment: Its staying on Login page again asking for credentials, But I have used correct credentials, its not showing usernam/password wrong! as per my code it should display error if credentials are wrong. I have already tested this.

Comment: @ashok, then you are probably not authenticating correctly. I.e. after the login operation, the HttpContext.Current.User.Principal is probably not showing as authenticated. How is the authentication done in the login page?

Comment: I have updated the question, username and password is sent to a Web server , It its authenticated then its returns a string "Success". and it is returning Success here.  Looks like I missed something here

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Forms authentication you need to create an authentication cookie if authentication is successful. Otherwise the ASP.NET subsystem will not know that the authentication was successful.

See this article:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/301240

Here is the relevant text from this article:

4.You can use one of two methods to generate the forms authentication cookie and redirect the user to an appropriate page in the cmdLogin_ServerClick event. Sample code is provided for both scenarios. Use either of them according to your requirement. 

•Call the RedirectFromLoginPage method to automatically generate the forms authentication cookie and redirect the user to an appropriate page in the cmdLogin_ServerClick event:

```
private void cmdLogin_ServerClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
if (ValidateUser(txtUserName.Value,txtUserPass.Value) )
    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(txtUserName.Value,
        chkPersistCookie.Checked);
    else
        Response.Redirect("logon.aspx", true);
}
```

•Generate the authentication ticket, encrypt it, create a cookie, add it to the response, and redirect the user. This gives you more control in how you create the cookie. You can also include custom data along with the FormsAuthenticationTicket in this case.

```
private void cmdLogin_ServerClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   if (ValidateUser(txtUserName.Value,txtUserPass.Value) )
   {
      FormsAuthenticationTicket tkt;
      string cookiestr;
      HttpCookie ck;
      tkt = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, txtUserName.Value, DateTime.Now, 
DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), chkPersistCookie.Checked, "your custom data");
      cookiestr = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(tkt);
      ck = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, cookiestr);
      if (chkPersistCookie.Checked)
      ck.Expires=tkt.Expiration;    
            ck.Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath; 
      Response.Cookies.Add(ck);

      string strRedirect;
      strRedirect = Request["ReturnUrl"];
      if (strRedirect==null)
            strRedirect = "default.aspx";
         Response.Redirect(strRedirect, true);
   }
   else
      Response.Redirect("logon.aspx", true);
}
```